# How to get the array difference of multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have 2 two arrays

```
$schedule = [
    "Monday" => [0 => "12:00", 1 => "01:20"],
    "Tuesday" => [0 => "04:20",1 => "12:00"],
];

$bookedSlots = [
    ["Monday" => "01:20"],
    ["Tuesday" => "04:20" ] 
];
```

Now I want the answer or result to return an array of the remaining available slots in which the booked slots should be eliminated from the schedule. like the result given below.

```
$availableSlots = $schedule - $bookedSlots; // [ "Monday" => [ 0 => "12:00"], "Tuesday" =>[ 0 => "12:00" ];
```

Comment: Please, share some code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So here I wrote a helper function to generalize the solution. You can use the below-mentioned function.

```
function find_diff($schedule, $booked_slots)
{
  $diff = [];
  foreach ($schedule as $day =>  $times) {
    $day_wise_slots = isset($booked_slots[$day]) ? $booked_slots[$day] : [];
    if (!is_array($day_wise_slots)) $day_wise_slots = [$day_wise_slots];
    $diff[$day] = array_diff($times, $day_wise_slots);

  }

  return $diff;
}
```

Functions used: [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried but it is throwing this exception, ErrorException: Array to string conversion at $diff[$day] = array_diff($times, $day_wise_slots);

Comment: What are the arguments that you are passing?

Comment: I exactly copied your solution. and passed the above arrays mentioned in my question

Comment: The array that you passed in the question was in wrong format would throw an error even while passing,  I have corrected the question. $schedule = [
    "Monday" => [0 => "12:00", 1 => "01:20"],
    "Tuesday" => [0 => "04:20",1 => "12:00"],
];

$bookedSlots = [
    ["Monday" => "01:20"],
    ["Tuesday" => "04:20" ] 
];

Comment: I print_r both arrays and here you can see https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqcCrPyKckd3tQwJF6uKUd3Ay-hI?e=sDd5gT

Comment: Can you share some working snippet https://paiza.io/projects/e/Btj52cUEZ3GWYTsBGoVOYw? I will try to debug it.

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/DM8lMnagSJTxCwLPSd-kBw .Have a look please

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/e/m3yWFY47sxLCSe1AVHd7DA corrected solution. The values in $bookedSlots variable were expected to be of type string.